# Test-SPSite (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: 2013, 2016, 2019

What say about this test?
The Test-SPSite team showed the following

1. SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Conflicting Content Types" RuleId
   =befe203b-a8c0-48c2-b5f0-27c10f9e1622,
2. SPSiteHealthResult Status=FailedWarning RuleName="Custom files" RuleId=
   cd839b0d-9707-4950-8fac-f306cb920f6c,
3. SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Lack of collections" RuleId=ee9671
   97-ccbe-4c00-88e4-e6fab81145e1,
4. SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Missing Parent Content Types" RuleI
   d=a9a6769f-7289-4b9f-ae7f-5db4b997d284...}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, in your site collections you have some custom files for which you are getting warning.

[**Customized File Rule:**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customized-files-found-during-site-collection-health-check-d2621cc5-d9a3-45f9-aa1b-eca4fb462485) This rule checks for any files that have been customized using a file editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer or Notepad or by changing some of the file properties.

[also check this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/run-site-collection-health-checks-in-sharepoint-2013)

In any repair or upgrade process these files will not work properly.

Other than that, i think your site is in good shape.

Comment: If you run Repair-SPSite?

Comment: same rule will triggered as customized files are hard to repair. check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf7b897d-5c3e-4d0c-8000-7ba9adda0fba/repairspsite-not-doing-anything?forum=sharepointadmin